# How to run ./a.out <filename.txt with xcode

Tags: c, xcode, command-line

I am trying to process a file with a small c language program by using `getchar()`. And I am trying to do this with xcode. Normally when I want to execute the code with command line arguments I will set the scheme with arguments, however, it does work when I want to add `<filename.txt` in the command line. I had the txt file in the same folder as the executable product.
Now I am trying to let xcode run the argument after I build my program, I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Update 21/09/14:

Here is my test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    int c = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        putchar(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my scheme configuration in Xcode. The .txt file is in the working directory folder.

[image]
[image]

Comment: On which operating system ? On Linux you can simply run the program in a terminal (perhaps even within `emacs` editor, using `M-x shell`) ...

Comment: You need to also set the working directory in the scheme, and then it should work.

Comment: I don't think using shell input redirection like this within Xcode is going to be easy to set-up.  I think you should pass the name of the file (using `$(PROJECT_DIR)`) to the program and have it open and read the file itself.

Comment: Seriously, I do this all the time - just set the working directory in the scheme and it will work.

Comment: could you please give me a sample? I am new to programming... Thansk a lot

Comment: It's just a setting in the scheme - no code involved - look at where you enter the command line arguments and there is also a field for environment variables and another for working directory. I'm not on my development machine right now or I'd post a screen shot, but it's really very simple and is covered in the Xcode help.

Comment: Hmm, I tried, but it seems not working... I set the working directory to the product folder and I had the txt file in there. I put the '<filename.txt' in the argument in scheme. I'm getting confused.

Comment: Edit your question to include a screen shot of how you have it set up.

Comment: I think the '<filename.txt' is slightly different than the normal command line argument that is why it is a bit different and got me stuck. I updated the post with pics and code, hope it could explain it.

Comment: That looks correct, assuming you're running the Debug build and that yout data file is in the Debug directory along with the executable ?

Comment: OK - my bad - it looks like I/O redirection does not work correctly in Xcode 4, 5 or 6 - the crazy things is that I'm sure this used to work in old versions of Xcode (2.x, 3.x). What seems to happen is that the redirection just gets passed to the executable like any other command line argument, so I guess you could check for this in your argument parsing code as a workaround, but it's a pain.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, now I just copy and paste the txt file content to xcode when it runs and use ctrl + d to let the program run through the file.